# Camera is revolving when rigidbody attached to player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, rigid-bodies

I am new to game development and trying to build an endless runner game just for my hands-on on Unity3D game development, it was running smoothly before applying jump functionality to the player, here are my code for player movement.

```
public class RockeyMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float rockyMoveForwardSpeed = 5f;
    public float rockyMoveLeftRightSpeed = 4f;

    public Vector3 jump;
    public float jumpForce = 2.0f;

    public bool isGrounded;
    Rigidbody rb;


    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        jump = new Vector3(0.0f, 2.0f, 0.0f);
    }

    void OnCollisionStay()
    {
        isGrounded = true;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * rockyMoveForwardSpeed, Space.World);


        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            if (this.gameObject.transform.position.x > LevelControl.leftSide)
            {
                transform.Translate(Vector3.left * Time.deltaTime * rockyMoveLeftRightSpeed);
            }
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            if (this.gameObject.transform.position.x < LevelControl.rightSide)
            {
                transform.Translate(Vector3.left * Time.deltaTime * rockyMoveLeftRightSpeed * -1);
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && isGrounded)
        {

            rb.AddForce(jump * jumpForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
            isGrounded = false;
        }

    }

 


}
```

**Player Inspector**
[image]

**Errors**
[image]

**Hierarchy**

As you can see I just drop Main Camera on to player so that camera follow player,

[That is how my game is behaving](https://youtu.be/K55Eh0XUF3E)

My game was working fine before implementing that jump functionality to the player. as i am new please tell me how to solve that issue which i am facing.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of attaching your camera as a child of a player you could use `PositionConstraint` just align your camera relative to the player with offsets then just attach the `PositionConstraint` component on your camera with following settings

[image: Position constraint settings]

By doing this your camera will only follow your player's position.

Comment: I think problem is with my physics, after adding Position Constraint, I still receiving weird behavior from game.

Comment: Make sure camera does not have any parent, it doesn't matter how you have implemented your movement script, it should not make you camera behave weirdly

Comment: @Digvijasinh my camera does not have any parent, its all alone as default